# How do you use ordinal response data with several random effects to do robust hypothesis testing?

Tags: mixed-model, p-value, model-selection, ordinal-data, robust

I want to explore the roles of lung presence and habitat on tadpoles' ability to tolerate low oxygen levels. My experimental design generated several measurements of "responsiveness" (on an ordinal scale from 1-6) per individual. Individuals were either subjected to a high oxygen treatment or a low oxygen treatment, and groups of 26 individuals were tested at the same time (half high O2 and half low O2). Significant effort was put into maintaining good experimental control within each run. These experiments were conducted in the field over the course of two months, on many different species. We considered habitat as a binary of "stream" vs "pond", and lung status as the binary "lunged" vs "lungless".

Simply put, I'm interested in the the effects of the predictors "treatment", "lung status", and "habitat" on "response", and especially the interactions between these factors. There are are clear biological implications if certain interaction terms have strong effects on response. But in many cases these effects are only meaningful in an interaction framework, because of the treatment effect. Do lungless tadpoles have lower tolerance to hypoxia? Is that tolerance only lower for lungless, stream tadpoles? My somewhat novice statistical background wants to look for p values of interaction terms and be done.

However ... these models clearly need random effects. I have a pretty long list of factors that likely influence response data, are not directly pertinent to my research question, and their effects are reasonably drawn from shared distributions. Some examples of such effects are: individual, species, genus, run, temperature (continuous), and amount of time into testing period (continuous).

My first question is how to go about doing hypothesis testing in this framework. Using the R package "ordinal", I can use the function clmm, which does produce p values, but I have a feeling that is not the way to go about this. My gut is that I should pick candidate models that do or do not include an interaction term of interest, then use AIC to determine if that added complexity is "worth it".

However, I haven't done that yet, because I'm not sure what to do with all these candidate random effects. Should they be intercept-only effects? Should I use all of them? Should I somehow do model-testing to eliminate fixed effects that aren't doing very much?

I'm sorry if I did not include critical information. This is my first posted question and I will learn from critical feedback.

I'm copying a model summary output when using several random effects and all fixed effects with interactions. (code = individual)

```r
mod_all = clmm(response_ordered ~ treatment*Habitat*Lungs + 
    (1|response_number) + (1|temp_difference) + (1|Code) + (1|Genus),
     data=full_data, Hess=TRUE)

summary(mod_all)

Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the Laplace approximation

formula: response_ordered ~ treatment * Habitat * Lungs + 
    (1 | response_number) + (1 | temp_difference) + (1 | Code) + 
    (1 | Genus)
data:    full_data

 link  threshold nobs logLik   AIC     niter      max.grad cond.H 
 logit flexible  2988 -3240.98 6513.96 1414(9734) 4.15e-04 3.1e+04

Random effects:
 Groups          Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Code            (Intercept) 2.090196 1.44575 
 temp_difference (Intercept) 0.868980 0.93219 
 Genus           (Intercept) 1.782582 1.33513 
 response_number (Intercept) 0.006289 0.07931 
Number of groups:  Code 436,  temp_difference 50,  Genus 15,  response_number 7 

Coefficients:
                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
treatmentlow                 3.8275     0.8206   4.664  3.1e-06 ***
Habitat                     -0.4370     1.6053  -0.272 0.785443    
Lungs                        1.4743     1.2664   1.164 0.244327    
treatmentlow:Habitat        -3.2785     0.9776  -3.354 0.000798 ***
treatmentlow:Lungs          -2.1401     0.7826  -2.735 0.006245 ** 
Habitat:Lungs                0.6239     1.6980   0.367 0.713289    
treatmentlow:Habitat:Lungs   1.5744     0.9810   1.605 0.108509    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error z value
no_touch|touch         -1.048      1.241  -0.845
touch|pinch             1.253      1.239   1.011
pinch|pinch_2           4.776      1.247   3.829
pinch_2|unresponsive    4.890      1.248   3.918
unresponsive|dead       7.101      1.262   5.626
(252 observations deleted due to missingness)
```